# How to write mathematical equation for an ARIMA(1,0,1)(1,0,0) + xreg model?

Tags: r, statistics, arima

I'm not entirely sure how to write out the equation for an ARMA(1,1)+S-ARMA(1,0) with an exogenous regressor model.

My attempt at writing it out with lag operators:

Unable to post equation due to less than 10 reputation points but heres the Latex code

$$(1-\phi_1L)(1-\Phi_1L^{16})Y_t=c+(1+\theta_1L)\varepsilon_t + x^{'}_t\beta$$

I'm not worried about the actual values of the coefficients, but with how to add xreg to a normal arima equation because I'm almost certain that my interpretation isn't correct.

```
# Load packages
library(quantmod)
library(xts)
library(stargazer)

# Get VIX data from yahoo finance
VIX <- getSymbols(Symbols = "^VIX", src = "yahoo",
                  type = "xts", auto.assign = FALSE)
# Only interested in closing price
VIX <- Cl(VIX)
# Aggregate data to weekly frequency
wVIX <- apply.weekly(VIX, FUN = last)
# Take Log Difference to get stationary time series
dlwVIX <- diff(log(wVIX))
dlwVIX <- na.omit(dlwVIX)

# Training and test samples
w_training_sample <- index(dlwVIX["2007-01-12/2019-01-04"])
w_test_sample <- index(dlwVIX["2019-01-11/"])

# Get SPY data to use as an external regressor
SPY <- getSymbols(Symbols = "SPY", src = "yahoo",
                  type = "xts", auto.assign = FALSE)
# Only interested in closing price
SPYcl <- Cl(SPY)
# Aggregate SPY to weekly frequency
wSPY <- apply.weekly(SPYcl, FUN = last)
# Take Log Difference to get stationary time series
dlwSPY <- diff(log(wSPY))
dlwSPY <- na.omit(dlwSPY)

# ARMA(p,q)+SARMA(P,Q) w/ xreg
warma11 <- arima(dlwVIX[w_training_sample], order = c(1,0,1),
                 seasonal = list(order = c(1,0,0), period = 16),
                 xreg = dlwSPY[w_training_sample])
```

Summary table:

```
=============================================
                      Dependent variable:    
                  ---------------------------
                               [             
                     ARMA(1,1)+S-ARMA(1,0)   
---------------------------------------------
ar1                         0.331**          
                            (0.158)          
                                             
ma1                        -0.530***         
                            (0.143)          
                                             
sar1                       0.146***          
                            (0.040)          
                                             
intercept                    0.005           
                            (0.003)          
                                             
SPY.Close                  -4.252***         
                            (0.167)          
                                             
---------------------------------------------
Observations                  626            
Log Likelihood              533.717          
sigma2                       0.011           
Akaike Inf. Crit.         -1,055.433         
=============================================
Note:             *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```